# Using cURL or DOM to webscrape

Tags: php, dom, html, web-scraping

I've been working on this for about four hours and have been all over the internet trying to understand it, so please be gentle.

I'd like to display a `div` from an external source on my php page. I've tried using`file_get_dom`, `simplexml_load_file`, `file_get_contents` with `preg_match_all`, then printed them on my page, but they don't work. cURLing is over my head from what I have seen and can't understand any of it, but I've been told it is the best way to do it. They all result in various errors when all I want is to grab the contents of an external `div`. What should I do?

An example would be scraping the `div id='hmenus'` on this page, then displaying it on my local page.

Thanks!

Comment: The methods you mention are all fine (except maybe for the preg_match_all one). "Doesn't work" isn't a good description to help you go forward, though. Maybe show some code that isn't working and any errors that you're getting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML/XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml)

Answer (score 1):

If `cURL` is over your head then perhaps try [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
$html = file_get_html($url);
echo $html->find('div[id=hmenus]', 0);
```